# Computing Non-zero End Digits of Large Factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, project-euler

Any large factorial will have a number of zero behind it, and one could write an expression to compute the number of trailing zeros, but how would one go about computing the non-zero end digits?

E.g. compute first 5 non-zero end digits of (10^12)!

Comment: Project Euler, [problem #160](http://projecteuler.net/problem=160) ?

Comment: For least significant non-zero digit see :http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath489.htm

Comment: How about in a base like 12 instead of 10?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130352/last-non-zero-digit-of-a-factorial?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this just now--a crucial fact is that there are more factors of 2 than of 5.

To formalize notation, let $v(N) $ be the largest positive integer such that $\large 10^{v(N))} | N$, and let $M(N) := \dfrac{N}{10^{v(N)}}$ denote the number of which we are trying to find the last 5 digits if $N = (10^{12})!$.

Hint: What can you say about $M(N) \mod 2^5$? How about $M(N) \mod 5^5$? How about $$ \Large M \left ( \prod_{\substack{ 1 \leq n \leq 10^{12} \\ 5 \not \,  \,| \,   n } }  n \right ) \mod 5^5?$$
How about
$$ \Large M \left ( \prod_{\substack{ 1 \leq n \leq 10^{12} \\ 25 \not \,  \,| \,   n } }  n \right ) \mod 5^5?$$
Can you see a pattern?

Comment: hey, you got it? That's great!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  if you wanted just the last digit, a naive approach would be to do all the multiplication mod 10, skipping the 0's. $ (1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9)^{10^{11}}$.  A second thought is that the $5$ swallows the $2$, so we can skip those.  This works fine for all the factors besides $2$ and $5$, which need some more thought...