# Last non zero digit of $n!$

Tags: number-theory, factorial, divisibility

What is the last non zero digit of $100!$?

Is there a method to do the same for $n!$?

All I know is that we can find the number of zeroes at the end using a certain formula.However I guess that's of no use over here.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130352/last-non-zero-digit-of-a-factorial) for a general formula. Or just do a search for "last non zero digit of n!" in this site, or look at the related links in to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question gets asked fairly frequently. There was originally a [problem on the AMC](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/2010_AMC_12A_Problems/Problem_23) asking for the last two digits. Here is [my post](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=150&t=531710&p=3037974#p3037974) on the single digit case, which is not all that much simpler than the two digit case.

Comment: I'm sure that this question has been asked before 2010 (year of the AMC question).

Comment: Oops, didn't check the date on that. For some reason, I had remembered it to be a lot earlier than 2010.