# First non-zero digit

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, infinite-product

In terms of n, which is the first non-zero digit of
$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n/2} (i)(n-i+1)$ for even n $\geq$ 6? Thank for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple points of clarification... First, your product is just a rephrasing of  the factorial of $n$. Second, by "first non-zero digit" I assume you mean "least significant" (or "rightmost", as people normally write numbers). Third, by "digit" I also assume you mean in the customary  base ten.

That being said, your question is equivalent to finding the first non-zero digit of $n!$ in base ten. Let's call this $d(n)$. If we lived in a world with a number system base that was prime, then there is a not-too-crazy closed form expression for this. However, since our base ten is a product of two primes, the situation is slightly more complex. Nevertheless, there is a nice recurrence relation for $d(n)$,  which is nicely described [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130352/last-non-zero-digit-of-a-factorial):
$$d(n)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    4d(\lfloor n/5\rfloor)\cdot d(\text{units digit of }n), & \hbox{if the units digit of }n\hbox{ is odd;} \\
    6d(\lfloor n/5\rfloor)\cdot d(\text{units digit of }n), & \hbox{if the units digit of }n\hbox{ is even.}
  \end{array}
\right.$$
If you wish, you can trace through this recursion to get an explicit formula.