# Find the last two non-zero digits of $70!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, chinese-remainder-theorem

The question itself is quite straightforward, however, I am unable to get an *exact* answer to the problem. I have narrowed it down to four possibilities one from $\{18, 43, 68, 93\}$.

### The approach

We begin by finding the number of zeros that are contained in $70!$. This is done as shown below:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{70}{5^n} \right\rfloor = 16
$$

And clearly

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{70}{2^n} \right\rfloor > \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{70}{5^n} \right\rfloor \qquad \qquad \text{(i)}
$$

So therefore we define some integer $N$ such that:

$$
N = \frac{70!}{5^{16}2^{16}}
$$

From here we will find the remainder of $N$ modulo $4$ and $25$ respectively so we can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to finish the problem.

##### Verifying mod 4

From (i) it is clear that $N$ will enough spare twos to be divisible by $4$. This leads us to the conclusion that:

$$
N \equiv 0 \pmod 4
$$

##### Verifying mod 25

We can split this part of the problem into two parts. Define another integer $M$ such that
$$
M = \frac{70!}{5^{21}}
$$
This allows us to write:
$$
\frac{1}{2^{16}} \cdot M = N
$$

###### Finding 2^16 mod 25

Trivially, we can find that

$$
2^{16} = 65536 \equiv 11 \pmod {25}
$$

###### Finding M mod 25

This one is a little trickier. To do this, we will use the fact that:

$$
(5n+1)(5n+2)(5n+3)(5n+4) \equiv -1 \pmod {25}
$$

Notice that we can group $M$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4)(6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9)\cdots(66\cdot67\cdot68\cdot69) \ &\times \\
(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4)(6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9)(11\cdot12\cdot13\cdot14) \ &\times \\
(1\cdot2)
\end{align*}
$$

Now, we can easily see:

$$
M \equiv (-1)^{12} \cdot (-1)^{3} \cdot {2} \equiv 23 \pmod {25}
$$

###### Bringing it together

Now we have the following equation

$$
N \equiv \frac{M}{2^{16}} \equiv \frac{23}{11} \pmod {25}
$$

This is where I got stuck.

From here I tried to write
$$\frac{23 + 25k}{11} \pmod{25}$$
and this yields four possible solutions $\{18, 43, 68, 93\}$. Is there a way that I can find the correct solution and/or a better way to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: First you say "The highest power of 5 that divides 70! is 5^16" and then you say "Let us define another integer, M = 70! / 5^21"?

Comment: So, to summarise, you have found N modulo 25, but you are stuck because the question was to find N modulo 100?

Comment: But remember that N = 0 mod 4. So N mod 100 cannot be 18, 43 or 93.

Comment: The last step is what you had planned to do with the Chinese remainder theorem: knowing N mod 25 and N mod 4, calculate N mod 100. But since 100 = 4 x 25, you don't even need the heavy artillery of the Chinese remainder theorem, and you can go directly from N = 18 mod 25, N = 0 mod 4 to N = 68 mod 100.

Comment: Not a coincidence: on my old high school pocket calculator, the highest factorial that can be computed explicitly is 69!.

Comment: 2 divides 70! to a higher power than 5, therefore from 18, 43, 68, 93 it cannot be odd and must be even, thus 18 or 68.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841331/find-last-5-significant-digits-of-2017 and all the links given there.

Comment: BTW, to compute $\frac{23}{11}$ modulo $25$ without paper and pen, you can use a bunch of elementary operations such as expanding, cancelling and addition of $25$:

$$\frac{23}{11}=\frac{-23}{-11}=\frac{2}{14}=\frac{1}{7}=\frac{-1}{-7}=\frac{24}{18}=\frac{4}{3}=\frac{54}{3}=18$$

Comment: "the highest factorial that can be computed explicitly is 69!" Whose last two nonzero digits could be multiplied by $7$ to give the result .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have residue $0\bmod4$ you are sure that the residue $\bmod100$ will be a multiple of $4$. So pick the solution out of your four that is a multiple of four.

There is also a minor error in your derivation. When you render

$M=[(1×2×3×4)(6×7×8×9)...(66×67×68×69)][(1×2×3×4)(6×7×8×9)(11×12×13×14)](1×2)$

you simplify this to $(-1)^{12}(-1)^3(2)\bmod 25$. But, properly, the first group has fourteen sets of four factors, so the first power of $-1$ should have exponent $14$.

Comment: Thanks for that! It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

> From here we will find the remainder of $N$ modulo $4$ and $25$
> respectively so we can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to finish the
> problem.
>
> $$ N \equiv 0 \pmod 4 $$
>
> $$ N \equiv \frac{M}{2^{16}} \equiv \frac{23}{11} \pmod {25} $$
>
> $$\color{red}{\text{THIS IS WHERE I GOT STUCK!}}$$

To simplify $\frac{23}{11} \pmod {25}$, you can compute the inverse of 11 mod 25, by solving the Diophantine equation $11 x - 25 q = 1$. This will give you $11^{-1} = 16 \pmod {25}$. Thus $N \equiv 23 \times 16 \equiv 18 \pmod{25} $.

Now you can apply your last planned step, which was to use the Chinese remainder theorem to go from $N \equiv 0 \pmod{4}, N \equiv 18 \pmod{25}$ to $N \equiv ?? \pmod{100}$.

But actually, since $100 = 25 \times 4$, we don't even need the heavy artillery here. Just list the 4 possibilities $\{18, 43, 68, 93\}$ and cross out the 3 which are not $\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.

We end up with $N \equiv 68 \pmod{100}$.

My computer confirms that result:
$$70! = 11978571669969891796072783721689098736458938142546425857555362864628009582789845319\color{red}{68}0000000000000000$$