# What is the last non-zero digit of $(\dots((2018\underset{! \text{ occurs }1009\text{ times}}{\underbrace{!)!)!\dots)!}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factorial, decimal-expansion

Without using computer programs, can we find the last non-zero digit of $(\dots((2018\underset{! \text{ occurs }1009\text{ times}}{\underbrace{!)!)!\dots)!}}$?

What I know is that the last non-zero digit of $2018!$ is $4$, but I do not know what to do with that $4$.

Is it useful that $!$ occurs $1009$ times where $1009$ is half of $2018$? If that is useful, then what if $1009$ was another value, say $1234$?

Any help will be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: have you tried smaller repeats ?

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee Even doing two factorials is an obscenely large number, a quick wolframalpha search shows $(2018!)! > 10^{10^{5000}}$

Comment: smaller inputs @Gabe . With start value 3 I can get $((3!)!)!$ but the next gives me a truncation error in PARI/GP.

Comment: Probably useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130352/last-non-zero-digit-of-a-factorial

Comment: or that $10^n!$ has the same last non-zero digit of $(9!)^{10^n-1\over 9}$

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari would you tell me about the source of the problem?

Comment: @Vulch I'm simply asking, please don't take it as offensive: why does the source matter?

Comment: @Sbsty It can indicate how hard the problem is or which methods are needed to solve it. For example, it could appear in a computer science / algorithms textbook, or a number theory textbook, or an "open problems" section in a mathematical journal, or maybe OP's friend asked the problem and does not know how hard it is.